# 3D scatter plot with million points, rotate and zoom it

Tags: python, matplotlib, bigdata, data-visualization, scatter-plot

Currently I am using `mpl_toolkits.mplot3d` with ~100k points. However, rotating the graph is very time-costly and zooming is impossible. Does anyone have suggestions on how to fix these problems?

Comment: The two solutions are (1) plot less points, since one wouldn't be able to perceive this large number of points anyways, (2) don't use matplotlib, other libraries like mayavi or pyqtgraph would probably be much faster.

Comment: More clear. Can't really add much in the way of content because the OP didn't upload any code but at least now it's obvious what he's asking.

Comment: You can use plotly to plot 3d figure. Not sure after rendering into js, it will fit your purpose.